# SharePoint 2016 workflow manager installation error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2016, workflow-manager-1.x

I found this article: "[SharePoint 2016: Step By Step Installation of Workflow Manager](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34407.sharepoint-2016-step-by-step-installation-of-workflow-manager.aspx)"

When I get to step 2 ([Install Workflow Manager 1.0 CU 2](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34413.sharepoint-)) I receive an error:

> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\sps2_\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\1343597488.xml.temp
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID 5nine
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Security
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID 5nine
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Security
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Backup
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Portal
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Backup
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Portal
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Backup
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Resource Provider
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID VMWare
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Hybrid Cloud
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Windows Azure Pack
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Cloud Assert
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID VMWare
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Hybrid Cloud
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Windows Azure Pack
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Cloud Assert
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID VMWare
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Hybrid Cloud
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Windows Azure Pack
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Cloud Assert
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Usage
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Billing
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Hybrid Cloud
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Windows Azure Pack
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Cloud Assert
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Usage
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Billing
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Hybrid Cloud
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Windows Azure Pack
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Cloud Assert
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Usage
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Billing
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Hybrid Cloud
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Windows Azure Pack
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Cloud Assert
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Usage
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Billing
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Hybrid Cloud
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Windows Azure Pack
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Cloud Assert
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Cloud Cruiser
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Billing
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Showback
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Cloud Cruiser
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Billing
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Showback
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID Terawe
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by current OS
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: h_tt_ps://aka.ms/webapplicationlist
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : h_tt_ps://aka.ms/webapplicationlist responded with 301
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
>
> ```
> h_tt_p/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
> Cache-Control: no-cache
> Pragma: no-cache
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
> Expires: -1
> Location: h_tt_ps://webgallery.microsoft.com/feed/webapplicationlist.xml
> Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
> X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
> X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
> X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
> Content-Length: 177
> Date: Thu, 27 Apr 2017 14:53:06 GMT
> Connection: keep-alive
> ```
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Content-disposition header: attachment
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes downloaded over the internet: '69999448'
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Number of bytes after possible decompression: '69999448'
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : File 'C:\Users\sps2_\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\NETFramework452\89F86F9522DC7A8A965FACCE839ABB790A285A63\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe' already exists, deleting old copy of the file
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Moving downloaded file 'C:\Users\sps2_\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp6F7E.tmp' to: C:\Users\sps2_\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\NETFramework452\89F86F9522DC7A8A965FACCE839ABB790A285A63\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Using cached file at C:\Users\sps2_\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WorkflowManagerRefresh\be5e294692e9f59b71026f2324f2243362789d9f\Workflow_Manager.msi instead of downloading from h_tt_p://download.microsoft.com/download/2/B/1/2B1AAC56-68D2-4B03-A102-00CFD9EDBC8E/en/Workflow_Manager.msi
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 :
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend" xmlns:wcm="h_tt_p://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State">
> <servicing>
>   <package action="configure">
>     <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft-Windows-ServerCore-Package" version="10.0.14393.0" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="AMD64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" versionScope="nonSxS" />
>     <selection name="IIS-WebServerRole" state="True" />    
>     <selection name="IIS-ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication" state="False" />
>     <selection name="IIS-IISCertificateMappingAuthentication" state="False" />
>     <selection name="IIS-URLAuthorization" state="False" />   
>   </package>
> </servicing></unattend>
> ```
>
> DownloadManager Error: 0 : Unattended setup returned '-2146498548'
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product IIS: Management Service done install completed
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 2
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Execute ASP.NET IIS Registration tool'. Commandline is: 'C:\Windows\sysnative\cmd.exe /C C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -iru'. Process Id: 5148
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Execute ASP.NET IIS Registration tool' is '0'
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install return code for product 'Execute ASP.NET IIS Registration tool' is Success
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Execute ASP.NET IIS Registration tool done install completed
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 3
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting MSI install for msi 'C:\Users\sps2_\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WorkflowClient\07AC0E3987F4ED7F910050F09278E925F73F1140\WorkflowManagerClient_x64.msi', commandline: 'ACTION=INSTALL REBOOT=ReallySuppress'
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : MSI install return value for product 'Workflow Manager Client 1.0 Cumulative Update 3' is '0'
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install return code for product 'Workflow Manager Client 1.0 Cumulative Update 3' is Success
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Workflow Manager Client 1.0 Cumulative Update 3 done install completed
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 4
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Workflow Manager Client 1.0 Cumulative Update 3 installation log: C:\Users\sps2_\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\logs\install\2017-04-27T17.53.05\WorkflowManagerClient_x64.txt
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)'. Commandline is: 'C:\Users\sps2_\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\VC11Redist_x64\ABE47E4996CF0409A794C1844F1FA8404032EDB2\vcredist_x64.exe /q /norestart'. Process Id: 8
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)' is '0'
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install return code for product 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)' is Success
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64) done install completed
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 5
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting MSI install for msi 'C:\Users\sps2_\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsFabric_1_0_960_0\f3d30ba00be17af30a841932eebcb06eb0123955\WindowsFabric.msi', commandline: 'STARTUPTYPE=disabled IACCEPTEULA=yes PRINCIPALUSER= PRINCIPALDOMAIN= ACTION=INSTALL REBOOT=ReallySuppress'
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : MSI install return value for product 'Microsoft Windows Fabric V1 RTM' is '0'
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install return code for product 'Microsoft Windows Fabric V1 RTM' is Success
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Microsoft Windows Fabric V1 RTM done install completed
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 6
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Microsoft Windows Fabric V1 RTM installation log: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\logs\install\2017-04-27T17.53.05\WindowsFabric.txt
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Microsoft Windows Fabric V1 CU1'. Commandline is: 'C:\Windows\sysnative\msiexec.exe /update "C:\Users\sps2_\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\WindowsFabric\f7a92fe4b397e73b3b38f3c7717754bf8fc742e3\WindowsFabricCU1.1.0.976.0.msp" /quiet /norestart IACCEPTEULA=yes PRINCIPALUSER= PRINCIPALDOMAIN='. Process Id: 11136
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Microsoft Windows Fabric V1 CU1' is '0'
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install return code for product 'Microsoft Windows Fabric V1 CU1' is Success
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Microsoft Windows Fabric V1 CU1 done install completed
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 7
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting MSI install for msi 'C:\Users\sps2_\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\ServiceBus_1_1\1C4BEC246A78DB77E92CAEC589C64FF7702F7AA8\Service_Bus.msi', commandline: 'WEBPI=1  ACTION=INSTALL REBOOT=ReallySuppress'
>   DownloadManager Information: 0 : MSI install return value for product 'Windows Azure Pack: Service Bus 1.1' is '0'
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install return code for product 'Windows Azure Pack: Service Bus 1.1' is Success
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Windows Azure Pack: Service Bus 1.1 done install completed
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 8
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Windows Azure Pack: Service Bus 1.1 installation log: C:\Users\sps2_\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\logs\install\2017-04-27T17.53.05\Service_Bus.txt
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Windows Azure Pack: Update for Service Bus 1.1 - .NET Framework 4.6 Compatibility (KB3086798)'. Commandline is: 'C:\Users\sps2_\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\ServiceBus_1_1_NETFramework46_Update\0fc102da1d4eb054f9180ea943b9ce088ef35ae4\AppServer-KB3086798-x64-EN.exe /quiet'. Process Id: 10700
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Windows Azure Pack: Update for Service Bus 1.1 - .NET Framework 4.6 Compatibility (KB3086798)' is '0'
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install return code for product 'Windows Azure Pack: Update for Service Bus 1.1 - .NET Framework 4.6 Compatibility (KB3086798)' is Success
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Windows Azure Pack: Update for Service Bus 1.1 - .NET Framework 4.6 Compatibility (KB3086798) done install completed
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 9
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2'. Commandline is: 'C:\Users\sps2_\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\NETFramework452\89F86F9522DC7A8A965FACCE839ABB790A285A63\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe /q /chainingpackage webpi /norestart /log C:\Users\SPS2_S~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_dotnetfx452install.html'. Process Id: 6636
>   DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2' is '0'
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install return code for product 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2' is Success
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 done install completed
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 10
>
> DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Dependency failed for product 'Workflow Manager 1.0 Refresh (CU2)'. Skipping install
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product Workflow Manager 1.0 Refresh (CU2) had a dependency fail. Increasing install product to 11
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Checking MU opt-in status.
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : MU Service found: Microsoft Update
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : MU Opt-in Status: usrsRegistered
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Attempting to launch: 'C:\Windows\system32\wuauclt.exe' /detectnow
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Successfully launched windows update scan
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: ManagementService, Install Status: InstallCompleted-Failure, Install Time: 00:00:04.4280208
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: ASPNET_REGIIS, Install Status: InstallCompleted-Success, Install Time: 00:00:00.1279921
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: WorkflowClient, Install Status: InstallCompleted-Success, Install Time: 00:00:01.2679570
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: VC11Redist_x64, Install Status: InstallCompleted-Success, Install Time: 00:00:03.4003137
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: WindowsFabric_1_0_960_0, Install Status: InstallCompleted-Success, Install Time: 00:00:17.0481974
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: WindowsFabric, Install Status: InstallCompleted-Success, Install Time: 00:00:15.9266922
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: ServiceBus_1_1, Install Status: InstallCompleted-Success, Install Time: 00:00:09.4122782
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: ServiceBus_1_1_NETFramework46_Update, Install Status: InstallCompleted-Success, Install Time: 00:00:07.9842457
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: NETFramework452, Install Status: InstallCompleted-Success, Install Time: 00:01:02.0704317
>
> DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product: WorkflowManagerRefresh, Install Status: DependencyFailed-None, Install Time: 00:00:00

Can anybody describe what's wrong?

2016-step-by-step-installation-of-workflow-manager-1-0.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment so leaving this as the answer.

What operating system are you installing workflow manager on?

I experienced the same issue when installing on Server 2016, which has.net 4.6 to resolved the problem I had to install workflow manger on a separate server running Server 2012 R2.

I believe this a server 2016 issues rather than a .net 4.6 issues.

The same dependency failed for product 'Workflow Manager 1.0 Refresh (CU2)'. because it didn't believe Workflow Manager 1.0 was installed, a reboot sorted this.